# Probability and disjoint events

Tags: probability

Let $A, B$ be events.

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint events, so are their complements?

My logic says that this statement is true. For example, if we define

$$A = \text{I passed the exam.}$$
$$B = \text{I failed the exam.}$$

$A$ and $B$ are disjoint because there is no situation in which both of them can happen simultaneously.

We also have the complements:
$$A^C = \text{I failed the exam.}$$
$$B^C = \text{I passed the exam.}$$

Again, there is no situation that both of them can happen simultaneously.

Am I wrong?

Comment: One example does not make a proof. The events $A$ and $B$ have another special property together in addition to being disjoint; can you see what that property is and why it matters?

Comment: @DavidK They are dependent? so they affecting each other? I'm sorry, this is supposed to be elementary but somehow it got me confused.

Comment: They were each other's complement, so when you complemented them they just switched places.

Comment: Even for elementary statements, in order to prove an "if" statement you need more than just an example. (To **disprove** an "if" statement, however, one counterexample is enough.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two events:

> C = I get > 60 marks in the mathematics test
> D = I get < 30 marks in the mathematics test

C and D are clearly disjoint, how about their complements?

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thanks a lot!!